# Spring4d How to make IEvent handle reference to procedure?

Tags: delphi, spring4d

when implementing an Event with the definition below Spring4D will add and invoke method but will not remove handler ( with IEvent<TaskItemChangeEvent>.Remove(MyProc) ) when asked as it does not identify it.

```
  {$M+}
  TaskItemChangeEvent = reference to procedure(const TaskItem: ITaskItem; Event: TTaskListEvent);
```

The following does work but I do not want to be forced to be bound to an object.

```
  {$M+}
  TaskItemChangeEvent = procedure(const TaskItem: ITaskItem; Event: TTaskListEvent) of Object;
```

I believe the issue is this line in TEventBase.Remove as a reference to procedure is not a TMethod?

```
  if TMethod(handlers[i]) = TMethod(handler) then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the compiler possibly creating different instances of the anonymous method between the place where you add and where you remove them.

Look at the following code:

```
var
  proc: TProc;

procedure Add(p: TProc);
begin
  proc := p;
end;

procedure Remove(p: TProc);
begin
  Writeln(PPointer(@proc)^ = PPointer(@p)^);
end;

procedure A;
var
  p: TProc;
begin
  p := procedure begin end;
  Add(p);
  Remove(p);
end;

procedure B;
begin
  Add(procedure begin end);
  Remove(procedure begin end);
end;

procedure C;
begin
  Add(A);
  Remove(A);
end;

begin
  A;
  B;
  C;
  Readln;
end.
```

You will notice that in `B` and `C` it will print `False` because the two anonymous methods being passed to `Add` and `Remove` differ from each other. While in `B` it's obvious in `C` it is not but the compiler actually transforms the code into this:

```
procedure C;
begin
  Add(procedure begin A(); end);
  Remove(procedure begin A(); end);
end;
```

That means if you want to use `IEvent<>` with a method reference type and be able to remove you need to keep the reference that you added in order for them to be equal and thus be able to be found when calling `Remove`.

The fact that internally in `TEventBase` the references are all handled as `TMethod` has nothing to do with that - when passing an anonymous method it is being transformed into a `TMethod`. After all an anonymous method type is an interface being backed by an object which the compiler creates which makes it possible to do such conversion and causes the necessity to keep the reference that was added in order to remove it.

Comment: Thanks @StefanGlienke you are right.  I was using the example you show as C and it was the hidden compiler magic which was tripping me up.